# how can i display one switch case at a time

Tags: php

If i have a case like this

```
<?php
$favcolor = "red"; /*<<<<<<<<<<<<<    this is just a random example    >>>>>>>>>>> */
switch ($favcolor) {
    case "red":
        echo "Your favorite color is red!";
        break;        
    case "red":
        echo "Your favorite color is blue!";
        break;
    case "green":
        echo "Your favorite color is green!";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Your favorite color is neither red, blue, nor green!";
}
?>
```

How can i display one case as a result and then another when clicked next; or something?

This is just an idea that will improve my website

Comment: You have two cases for `red`?

Comment: This sounds like something you'd use javascript for; unless by `then another when clicked next` you mean with a form submission but in that instance it should just work the same..

Comment: Is the second `case "red"` a typo? Because the message it displays says "blue".

Comment: @Bamar it's not a typo, it's output is  'you're favorite color is green' and 'is red' at the same time. i'm trying to find a way for it to display one at a time

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two cases with the same value.

Well, I mean, you can. However, it's only ever going to use the first instance of "red" that it finds when it traverses the switch.

You would either have to have two separate functions, one called on the original page, and the other called when "Next" is clicked, OR you would have to have an additional variable available to your switch function.

```
$favcolor = 'red';
switch($favcolor){
    case "red":
        if(isset($next) && ($next == TRUE)) {
             echo 'Your favorite color is red and you clicked "Next"!';
        } else {
             echo 'Your favorite color is red!';
        }
        break;
    .....
}
```

Comment: what if i have more than 2 'red's and i want to display one at one time on the webpage. the 'red' is basically a searched term, and if there are more than one answers, it would display one at a time.

Comment: @DarkSterix The `switch` statement should be inside a loop that selects the appropraite case for each match.